# Own Object can't be added to ArrayList. instead all objects are overwritten

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I try to determine the error since yesterday, but did not find him. All I know is where he must be placed approximately. But now to the topic.

For my app I have created a separate class with the name `Player`. Now if I make an ArrayList with this class, a newly added object overwrites all existing objects. So:

ArrayList empty -> Player is stored in ArrayList
ArrayList already contains a Player -> ArrayList now contains the newest Player instance two times
  etc.

Here is my code corresponding to:

**Player Object**

```
public Player(String n, int m, int t) {
    name = n;
    money = m;
    tip = t;
}

public String getName() {
    return this.name;
}

public int getMoney() {
    return this.money;
}

public int getTip() {
    return this.tip;
}

public String toString() {
    return this.name + "\n Tipp: " + this.tip + " | Einsatz: " + this.getMoney() + " ,- €";
}
```

**Creating the ArrayList**

```
public void addPlayertoEvent(String name, int money, int tip) {
    Player p = new Player(name, money, tip);

    playerList.add(p);

    playerListString.add(p.toString());

    lvPlayers.setAdapter(null);

    ArrayAdapter<String> playerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(AddEventActivity.this, R.layout.list_items, playerListString);
    lvPlayers.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    lvPlayers.setAdapter(playerAdapter);

    etTip.setText("");
    etName.setText("");

    for(int i = 0; i < playerList.size(); ++i) {
        Log.e("AL", "" + playerList.get(i).getName() + " " + playerList.get(i).getMoney() + " " + playerList.get(i).getTip());
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to read your question one more time and figure out if it possible to understand what are you asking for.

Comment: Are you sure your class variables are not static?

Comment: Sorry for my bad english. At what Point you don't unerstand my question?

Comment: Show the full classes and all the places where you invoke methods and ArrayList initialization

Comment: I agree with @AlexisC. I bet that `name`, `money`, and `tip` in your `Player` class are static.

Comment: Same as above, @AlexisC. is on to something. We can't say for sure unless we can see the full source for class `Player`.